# Python. Формирование многоуровневого dict из list

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции, dict

Здравствуйте!

Вот пример данных:

```
x = [
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 2),
    (6, 4),
    (7, 4),
    (8, 5),
    (9, 6),
    (10, 6)
]
```

Как из этого получить вот такой словарь:

```
y = {
    1: {
        2: {
            4: {
                6: {
                    9: {}, 
                    10: {}
                }, 
                7: {}
            },
            5: {
                8: {}
            }
        }, 
        3: {}
    }
}
```

Т.е. в каждом элементе списка есть кортеж из двух элементов.

Каждый второй элемент кортежа должен стать ключем словаря, в который вложен словарь с ключем из первого элемента кортежа.

Второй элемент кортежа используется только тогда, когда он уже использовался как первый, за исключением начала списка.

Суть в том, что не ясно, как корректно сформировать цепочку зависимостей - первый элемент кортежа от второго. Т.е. к 1 относятся 2 и 3, к 2 затем относятся 4 и 5, к 4 - 6 и 7, к 5 - 8, и т.д.

Comment: @jfs, сложность в том, что не ясно, как корректно сформировать цепочку зависимостей - первый элемент кортежа от второго и т.д. т..е. к 1 относятся 2 и 3, к 2 затем относятся 4 и 5, к 4 - 6 и 7, к 5 - 8, и т.д. 
Разбиение на более простые шаги - наверное рекурсивный поиск по вложенным словарям. Как это выполнить не ясно пока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = [                                                                       
    (2, 1),                                                                 
    (3, 1),                                                                 
    (4, 2),                                                                 
    (5, 2),                                                                 
    (6, 4),                                                                 
    (7, 4),                                                                 
    (8, 5),                                                                 
    (9, 6),                                                                 
    (10, 6)                                                                 
]                                                                           

x.sort()                                                                    

d = {}                                                                      
for v, k in reversed(x):                                                    
    if k not in d:                                                          
        d[k] = {}                                                           
    if v not in d:                                                          
        d[k][v] = {}                                                        
    else:                                                                   
        d[k][v] = d[v].copy()                                               
        del d[v]                                                            

print(d)
```

Обходить массив удобнее с конца, что и делается. Рекурсия тут не нужна, достаточно цикла. У вас в примере входной массив уже отсортирован лексикографически -- это необходимо для правильной работы алгоритма. На случай, если такая упорядоченность не гарантируется -- добавил `x.sort()`. Если гарантируется -- можете эту строчку удалить.

Результат работы:

```
{1: {2: {4: {6: {9: {}, 10: {}}, 7: {}}, 5: {8: {}}}, 3: {}}}
```